# PHP unexpected T_ELSE

Tags: php

Im quite new to PHP just trying some basics and as I was writing some script i found error that I can't fix myself. It says

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /xyz.php on line 22

I will paste here lines from 20 to 24

```
echo ("To rownanie nie ma rozwiazan w zbiorze liczb rzeczywistym");
}
else {
    if ($delta == 0){
$wynik = - $B / 2 * $A;
```

and the whole script if needed

```
<?php
$A = 1;
$B = 1;
$C = -2;
//wyswietlenie parametrow rownania
echo ('Parametrami rownania sa: <br>');
echo ("A = $A, B = $B, C = $C <br>");
//sprawdzenie czy jest ono kwadratowe
if ($A == 0){
    echo("To nie jest rownanie kwadratowe! A = 0!");
}
else {
    $delta = $B * $B - 4 * $A * $C;
    if ($delta < 0);{
        echo ("Delta < 0 <br>");
        echo ("To rownanie nie ma rozwiazan w zbiorze liczb rzeczywistym");
    }
    else {
        if ($delta == 0){
            $wynik = - $B / 2 * $A;
        echo ("Rozwiazanie: x = $wynik <br>");
        }
        else {
            $wynik = ( - B + sqrt($delta)) / 2 * $A
            echo ("rozwiazanie x1 = $wynik");
            $wynik = ( - B - sqrt($delta)) / 2 * $A
            echo (", x2 = $wynik");
        }
    }

}


?>
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: AND you don't have ;s after the / 2 * $A

Answer (score 2):

You have a wayward semicolon on this line:

```
if ($delta < 0);{
```

It should be:

```
if ($delta < 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($delta < 0);{
```

replace with

```
if ($delta < 0){
```